# Firebase V9 getUser/getAuth. trying to set [user] to the user auth state

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server, backend

[trying to set [user] to the auth state for the user so that it will run if the user is signed in else not. firebase v9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CUaE.png)

Comment: Wait what is the question actually? And also paste the code and not an image so that people can copy and test from their end

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)